# How to loop through each JSON block in an array

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

How to loop through each JSON block in an array? For example, I want to iterate over each JSON block (NOT each element) and send it as a body in an API call.

```
print(json_data)
```

Output as below.

```
[
{
   "occurrences": "1",
   "post_title": "Test 9",
   "ID": "17"
},
{
   "occurrences": "2",
   "post_title": "Test 8",
   "ID": "19"
},
{
   "occurrences": "5",
   "post_title": "abc",
   "ID": "11"
}
]
```

Comment: could you provide an example of what you want to get?

Comment: where is your attempt at this? StackOverflow title "Where developers learn, share and build careers".

Comment: What you have is a _list_ of _dictionaries_, not an _array_ of _JSON blocks_.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
import csv

fieldnames = ("occurrences", "post_title", "ID")
api_list = list()

with open("csv_file.csv", 'r') as data_file: # Pass Csv file in here
     reader = csv.DictReader(data_file, fieldnames)
     for i in reader:
         api_list.append(i)


for i in api_list:
    print i  # Will print each JSON Block ( Send it to API from here)
```

*Hope this answers your question!!!*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have it as JSON array. So, it is printing as below...one character per line...

[
{
"
N
a
m
e
"
:
............................

Comment: what do u mean by json array. can u show your input?

Comment: I'm parsing a CSV file..
data = []
fieldnames = ("occurrences", "post_title", "ID")
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)

Comment: Can u show your csv too so that i can see what kind of data is in there..

Comment: occurrences,post_title,ID
1,Test 9, 17
2,Test 8, 19

Comment: Output as below. I need JSON.
OrderedDict([('occurrences', 'occurrences'), ('post_title', 'post_title'), ('ID', 'ID')])
OrderedDict([('occurrences', '1'), ('post_title', 'Test_9'), ('ID', ' 17')])
OrderedDict([('occurrences', '2'), ('post_title', ' Test_9'), ('ID', ' 199')])

Comment: How come you are getting Ordered Dict I have not used Ordered Dict anywhere

Comment: Is it because I'm using Python3?

Comment: Or let say I have following in memory. How can I iterate through each JSON block.
[{"occurrences": "1", "post_title": "Test 9", "ID" : "17"}, {"occurrences": "2", "post_title": "Test 8", "ID" : "29"}]

Comment: It is nothing to do with Python 3. You can iterate in the mentioned JSON using above code only.

Comment: How can I iterate for each JSON block.
[{"occurrences": "1", "post_title": "Test 9", "ID" : "17"}, {"occurrences": "2", "post_title": "Test 8", "ID" : "29"}]

Comment: `x =  [{"occurrences": "1", "post_title": "Test 9", "ID" : "17"}, {"occurrences": "2", "post_title": "Test 8", "ID" : "29"}]`
`for i in x:`
       `print i`